# Dynamically updating force-directed graphs using d3JS

Tags: typescript, d3.js, nuxtjs3

I am currently working on a **Force-directed** graph with d3JS.
I am fairly new to d3 so I have based my (buggy) solution on tutorials and documentation.

Simply put I have an endpoint that supplies me with an object of node & link lists (in my code its a prop) periodically (every 5 seconds) and whenever I try to update my graph, I end up redrawing the entire graph on top of the old one.

Here is what I would like to achieve: A graph that dynamically adds, deletes & updates the graph without:

1. redrawing the entire graph
2. applying some crazy forces on the nodes making them move around, even after the simulation has finished. (the simulation should just apply to the updated nodes)

I am using NuxtJS v3 as my primary framework, although I think that's not too relevant.

Here is my implementation so far:

```
<template>
  <div id="graph">
    <svg id="graph-svg" width="960" height="600"></svg>
  </div>
</template>
```

I access the svg using its id and use d3 to display the graph:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref,watch } from 'vue';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const props = defineProps({
  data: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});
const { data } = props;
const metaData = ref();
let nodes, edges, simulation, svg;
let link, node;

// Watch for changes in the data prop
watch(() => props.data, async (newVal) => {
  if (newVal) {
    // Update the metadata and nodes/edges arrays
    metaData.value = props.data.graphStatistics;
    nodes = Object.values(props.data.nodes);
    edges = Object.values(props.data.edges);

    // Initialize the graph
    await initGraph();
  }
}, { immediate: true });


// Initialize the graph
const initGraph = async () => {
  // Select the SVG element and set its dimensions
  svg = d3.select("#graph-svg")
      .attr("width", window.innerWidth)
      .attr("height", window.innerHeight);

  // Create the force simulation
  simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(edges).id((d: { id: any; }) => d.id).distance(300).strength(1))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-7000))
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2))
      .force("x", d3.forceX().strength(0.5))
      .force("y", d3.forceY().strength(0.5))
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(10));

  // Append the links
  link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#999")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(edges, (d) => d.id)
      .join("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1);

  // Append the nodes
  node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#fff")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes, (d) => d.id)
      .join("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .attr("fill", "#537B87");

  // Update the positions of the nodes and links on each tick of the simulation
  simulation.on("tick", () => {
    link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

    node
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  });
};

</script>
```

It should also be noted that atm when the graph is redrawn it is instantiated in the top-left & not in the center.

Thanks in advance, I have completely given up & asking on here is my last option. I have been working on this for about a week now and still cannot figure it out. The other SO posts have brought me nowhere since they do not achieve a smooth updated graph.

Thanks again!!

Comment: The graph is redrawn because each update you append a new `g` and conduct a join with that, leaving the old `g`(s) alone. Append the `g` once outside the update function. The re-initialization of the graph happens because you are replacing the nodes with new nodes that are un-initialized - the force modifies the objects you pass to it adding x and y coordinates, among other properties, passing new objects to the simulation will cause the nodes to be initialized with new x,y properties without regard for where the original nodes were.

Comment: @AndrewReid thank you very much! The graph is coming along nicely, although I still have a problem regarding the updates. You mention I should update the data instead of overwriting it and although the nodes don't seem to suffer from any issues, the links are. When the data is passed I update the links using `.merge()` but for some odd reason all, but one, link dissappear. Is there some other operation I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you inspect the svg, do you see lots of line elements with no coordinates and you can confirm the links array has more than one element in it? I’m on a mobile device so I haven’t had a chance to mock up your code to test it, I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! There are indeed line elements but only one of the elements has x1,y1,x2,y2 variables. I think the links are still being overwritten, although I don't know why. For reference this is the operations I am running to update the links. Updating the links: `link = link.data(edges, (d) => d.id);`. removing the links that are deleted: `link.exit().remove();`. and then updating the svg links: `link.enter()....merge(link);`

Comment: The edge force id refers to the node id - unless your links have id values (which should not be necessary), you should just be using selectAll(“line”).data(edges).join(…)… (Yes, I’m suggesting reselecting the links - just to reduce the scope for other issues creeping in - still without a device to mock up anything as I’m on the road).

Comment: @AndrewReid I researched some more and am now using the update pattern instead of `.merge()`. The nodes/links are not even being loaded into the svg, and when they are(trying out different solutions), they are not moved by the simulation and spawn in the default position(top-left). For reference I am using the following for the update pattern: load in new data:`node = svg.selectAll("circle").data(nodes)`, add new data: `node = svg.selectAll("circle").enter().append("circle");` , delete old data: `node.exit().remove();`. Thank you again for responding even tho you are on the road

Comment: @AndrewReid I have looked at the update pattern some more and still cannot figure it out, any chance you could help me?

Comment: Hey Andrew, I have figured out a way to succesfully update the graph. The only issue I still have is the animation. It seems that the simulation is restarting the graph, therefor the positions of the elements are changed, which is not very smooth. is there a way to smooth out the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time I found a solution. I'm quite happy with the result & hopefully it can help some other person who is desperately trying to find a solution.

```
//initialize this at onMounted, no data is needed
initChart() {
     this.svg= d3.select(this.$refs.svg)
        .attr("viewBox", [-window.innerWidth / 2, -window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight])//this will center the graph
        .attr("width", window.innerWidth)
        .attr("height", window.innerHeight);

     this.link = this.svg.append("g")
        .attr(...)//your styling
        .selectAll("line");
     this.node = this.chart.append("g")
        .attr(...)//your styling
        .selectAll("circle");
}

//create a method for the simulation ticks
ticked() {
     this.link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

      this.node
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
}

//here is the ACTUAL updating
updateChart({nodes, edges}) {
      // now this is probably the most important part, and comes directly from mike bostocks implementation
      // Make a shallow copy to protect against mutation, while
      // recycling old nodes to preserve position and velocity.
      const old = new Map(this.node.data().map(d => [d.id, d]));
      nodes = nodes.map(d => ({...old.get(d.id), ...d}));
      edges = edges.map(d => ({...d}));

      this.link = this.link
        .data(edges, d => [d.source, d.target])
        .join(enter => enter.insert("line", "circle")
          .attr(...))//your styling
     );

      this.node = this.node
        .data(nodes, d => d.id)
        .join(enter => enter.append("circle")
          .attr()//your styling
          .call(node => node.append("title")// this is a tooltip
            .text(d => d.name))
        );

     // this is also very important as it restarts the simulation so the graph actually looks like it is being updated in real time
      this.simulation.nodes(nodes);
      this.simulation.force("link").links(edges);
      this.simulation.alpha(1).restart().tick();
      this.ticked();
    },
```

I hope this helps!